# Get numbers weekday/month between two dates and increase dates

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdate

I'm developing an iOS app in which I'm selecting date and time from calendar and giving option to add event in that date and time and also providing repeat option if they want to repeat that event for specific amount of time like daily/weekly/monthly/yearly. And also I'm asking for date till event should repeat to prevent infinite problem!!. When user save the event i'm passing flag according to repetition like (0-Never, 1-Daily, 2-Weekly, 3-Monthly, 4-Yearly) and saving all into database with single entry.

[image: 1]

Now when I get data from database I'm checking that flag and according to that i'm populating events.

I've done daily repeat like this:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.current
                let unitFlags = Set<Calendar.Component>([ .day])
                let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(unitFlags, from: date!, to: lastDate!)
                let dayCount = dateComponents.day
                print(dayCount!)

while date! < lastDate! {
                    date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1,  to: date!)!
                        print(date!)
                }
```

and it is working fine. now when I go for weekly and suppose I've selected date is **23rd November 2018** but when I repeat it ***weekly*** I've to get which day is there on this date. and also I've selected date **21st January 2019** as ***last date***. so now I want to repeat this weekly event till this last date means if day time on selected date is ***SUNDAY*** then I need all Sundays till end date.

How can I get that or what conditions I should put in this code to get work done?

Thank you in  advance!

Comment: To help people help you edit your question: "And some how I got this work done by adding 7 days..." - show your code; "but there are issues if February comes between because of 28/29 days according to leap year" - show/explain these "issues".

Comment: @CRD thank you for quick response i'm updating question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get date from another date byAdding days, months, etc. you don't have to worry about leap-year because `Calendar` counts with leap-years.

**Adding a week**

```
date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7,  to: date!)!
```

**Adding a month**

```
date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1,  to: date)!
```

**Adding a year**

```
date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1,  to: date)!
```

Comment: thank you for response and this is working. I've one another question related to this question!

Comment: @Mr.Desai What another question?

Comment: how can I achieve same thing for monthly and yearly?

Comment: in month it has issue.. i've selected date is 29th and till January it worked fine but from February it automatically changed from 29th to 27th and from onward it saved 27th

Comment: @Mr.Desai yes, it does. Better way for monthly repeating would be if you just added for example 30 days

Comment: sorry i didn't get it.

Comment: adding 30 days also won't help because one month has 30 and one has 31 days it cannot work in that situation!

Comment: @Mr.Desai, yes, it won’t help, because you are adding just 30 days. So there is no way how to add month to 30.1 and get 30.2 when January has just 28/29 days. So it will always return the latest day in January. Monthly repeating is more individual than weekly, yearly...